# Эмуляция метода .reverse()

Tags: javascript, массивы, reverse

Проверьте меня пожалуйста.
Правильно ли я сделал?

Задача: Напишите функцию, которая эмулирует работу метода reverse. Т.е. создает новый массив на основе arr13 с обратным порядком элементов и выводит в out-13.

```js
let arr13 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
let btn13 = document.querySelector('button.b-13');
let div13 = document.querySelector('div.out-13');
btn13.onclick = function f13() {
    let tsk13 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr13.length; i++) {
        tsk13.push(arr13[i]);
    }
    for (let i = tsk13.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        div13.innerHTML += tsk13[i] + ' ';
    }
    div13.innerHTML += '<br>' + ' ';
    tsk13 = arr13;
}
```

```html
<button class="b-13">BUTTON_TASK-13</button>
    <div class="out-13"></div>
```

---

А так будет верно?

```js
let arr13 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
let btn13 = document.querySelector('button.b-13');
let div13 = document.querySelector('div.out-13');
btn13.onclick = function f13() {
    let tsk13 = [];
    for (let i = arr13.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tsk13.push(arr13[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < tsk13.length; i++) {
        div13.innerHTML += tsk13[i] + ' ';

    }
    console.log(tsk13);
    div13.innerHTML += '<br>' + ' ';
    tsk13 = arr13;
}
```

```html
    <button class="b-13">BUTTON_TASK-13</button>
    <div class="out-13"></div>
```

Comment: в коде нет функции эмулирующей `reverse`. Кроме того, `reverse` не возвращает новый массив.

Comment: Нет. Вы просто выводите элементы в обратном порядке. Если убрать из Вашего кода первый цикл, а во втором цикле `tsk13` заменить на `arr13`, то ничего не изменится.

Comment: @Yaant понял. А как будет правильно сделать?

Comment: Теперь уже лучше. Но непонятен смысл присваивания в конце `tsk13 = arr13`. Ну и @Grundy уже указал на противоречие в формулировке задания. То ли нужно сэмулировать `reverse`, который изменяет исходный массив, а вовсе не создает новый, и ничего сам по себе не выводит, то ли создать новый массив и вывести его.

Comment: @Yaant понял. Да, присваивание в конце tsk13 = arr13 ничего не меняет. Убрал его. По поводу формулировки, такое вот задание попалось...

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через деструктивное присваивание менять местами пары:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

Array.prototype.myReverse = function(){
    for(let i=0; i<=this.length/2|0; i++){
        [this[i], this[this.length - 1 - i]] = [this[this.length - 1 - i], this[i]];
    }
}

arr.myReverse();

console.log(arr);
```

Или применить безусловную обратную сортировку:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

Array.prototype.myReverse = function(){
    this.sort(() => -1);
}

arr.myReverse();

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.